# 4 convex sets in a plane have a point in common

Tags: optimization

> Let $X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4$ be four sets in the plane such that any three of them have a point in common. Do all four of them have to have a point in common? What if sets are convex?

**Attempt:** I think all of them should not have a point in common, but I dont how them being convex can influence the answer. Thanks for help.

Comment: This works for convex sets: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helly's_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to come up with a counter-example if the sets are not-convex.

If the sets are convex, read the [technique of Helly's Theorem](https://brilliant.org/assessment/techniques-trainer/hellys-theorem/).

Answer (score 1):

As a counter example think of a square $A_1A_2A_3A_4$ and pick $X_i=A_{i-1}A_i \cup A_iA_{i+1}$ (notation modulo $4$).